# Worklight build inserts illegal characters into Javascript files

Tags: javascript, build, ibm-mobilefirst

When I build my Worklight projects, the Worklight builder inserts illegal characters at the beginning of javascript files. The builder typically inserts two lines to the top of each javascript file when building: a blank line followed by a line like "/* Javascript content from ... in folder ... */".  In my case, the first line contains illegal characters that cause errors when browsers try to load the javascript files.  Below are some facts that may be helpful:

- The build worked fine before, and then one day this problem started.
- Build and deploy would complete successfully, but testing using the simulator would fail.
- Same problem with multiple Worklight projects.
- I reinstalled another Juno 4.2.2 + Worklight Studio, and the problem persists.
- Tried creating a brand new workspace and that didn't work.
- Illegal characters are inserted into all javascript files, regardless of environment (common, android, and ipad)
- Tried using different encodings (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, US-ASCII, UTF-16, system default) in run configuration
- OS: Windows XP SP3
- Worklight version: Studio - 6.0.0.201309262018; IBM JQM and Dojo Mobile Tools - 6.0.0.201309262019

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned a lot of details except for the Worklight version. Please edit the question with this information. Do you have sample project to provide? Did you try using a new workspace and then create a new Worklight project in it?

Comment: Worklight version added; tried creating a new workspace and pulled in other projects that built with no problem before; but did not create a new project for testing...

Comment: Please try with a new application in the new workspace.

Comment: BTW, just for the sake of completeness, please also take a new instance of Eclipse (extract from the zip) and install Worklight Studio and see if it happens there too (with a new and imported project); this sounds like environment setup issue.

Comment: The Eclipse + WL Studio is a fresh install as I mentioned in my original post.  I created a brand new WL app and added an ipad environment.  When compiled, the same problem persists.

Comment: Where can I find configs for the WL Application Builder? Can I turn off the comment insertion into javascript files during build?

Comment: When you create a new project, the files are generated with the comments; you cannot create a Worklight project w/out them, but you can manually remove them.

Comment: I cannot recreate your issues; do you have another machine to try this on?

Comment: No, we are not talking about the same comments. Please read my original post more carefully. JS files were created with comments when a project is created, and there is no problem with that, no illegal character there.  It's when the builder copies the JS files into build artifacts that it inserts 2 lines at the top of each JS file, and that's when the illegal characters are inserted.

Comment: I was unable to replicate this problem on any other PCs with similar configuration. And that's why I just to be able to turn this crazy insertion off at build time.

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing that could cause this is if using IBM Java. Try installing Oracle Java 6 and above and see if it continues to happen.